# Rails 4 rake db:migrate causes invalid route error after Devise install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rake

I ran into a problem while doing the Authentication tutorial in the *Authentication with Rails 4 in Action* book.

I added `gem "devise", "~> 3.4.1"` to my Gemfile, ran `bundle`, and ran the generator `rails g devise:install`.

Then I generetated users like it was written in book with: `rails g devise user`.

Until this part everything was ok. Then I ran `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and got this error:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session' 
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:360:in `block in devise_session'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:359:in `devise_session'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:249:in `block (4 levels) in devise_for'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:249:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:249:in `block (3 levels) in devise_for'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:452:in `with_devise_exclusive_scope'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:248:in `block (2 levels) in devise_for'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:351:in `block in devise_scope'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:350:in `devise_scope'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:247:in `block in devise_for'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `devise_for'
/home/rafal/ruby_workspace/ticketee/config/routes.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/rafal/ruby_workspace/ticketee/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/rafal/ruby_workspace/ticketee/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rafal/ruby_workspace/ticketee/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is my `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
    root "projects#index"

    resources :projects do
      resources :tickets
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post the contents of `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: I posted it as an answer

Comment: Okomikeruko's solution below looks legit. If it works, you should consider accepting it as the answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/249307.  Also, please don't post data as an answer—either 1) **edit** your question to include it; or 2)  post it elsewhere like https://gist.github.com and include the link in your question using **edit**.

Comment: @Okomikeruko looks good - looks like it should work please confirm OP

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've got case of bad nesting

It should look like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "projects#index"
  devise_for :users
  resources :projects do
    resources :tickets
  end
end
```